# How event driven systems work?

Tags: events

This question bugs me. How event handling systems works?

what i understand is that there is must be a loop that waits for a message or something then activates a portion of a code. I know it is most likely a wrong idea but i need to understand how it works (abstractly)?

if there are diagrams that can explain it that would be good !

Comment: Do you mean at use level or an implementation level?  Either way, it's too broad of question for SO, but someone may be able to point you in the right direction.

Comment: I meant the two but i wanted to know about the implementation level more.

Comment: Am not very familiar with the low level implementation of eventing, but I would imagine that it's based around hardware interrupts.  At the end of the day, hardware interrupts are the only way to avoid continual polling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking about events in C# suppose that they are just implementation of 
Publisher/Subscriber or Observer patterns.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

In short, there is no waiting, subscriber just gives to publisher a code (via delegate) to invoke when publisher fires an event.